# How to create a real one-to-many relationship with KeyValueObjectMapping

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm new to KeyValueObjectMapping (https://github.com/dchohfi/KeyValueObjectMapping) so my question might sound easy: how to create the two relationships of a one-to-many relationship?

For instance, let's take the example of the User that has many tweets:

1) There's a NSArray of tweets in the User model
2) There's a User property in the Tweet model

I figured out to do 1) very easily but can't find a way to do the 2) link. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The github repo has been forked and viteinfinite created a [fix](https://github.com/viteinfinite/KeyValueObjectMapping/commit/1e8d48af4c2743effe45a18187d6c69345899894) :

Now it is possible doing what I wanted, for instance:

```
DCCustomInitializeBlock customBlock = ^(__weak Class classOfObjectToGenerate, NSDictionary *values, id parentObject) {
   id object = [[classOfObjectToGenerate alloc] init];
   object.parentTweet = parentObject;
   return object;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In dot-notation (use the valueForKey equivalent if necessary):

```
user.tweets = @[tweet1, tweet2];
tweet1.user = user;
tweet2.user = user;
```

Comment: I am using KeyValueObjectMapping. The mapping is not as straightforward as it is in your answer.

Comment: Yes, but you can see how it works in principle. Have you considered Core Data? You get the object graph right out of the box.

Comment: I know how it works, but here I specially need to use KeyValueObjectMapping, not Core Data.